# Eiffel: Is there a way to test a given Generic parameter of a Class without any attached instance of it?

Tags: generic-programming, eiffel

Is there a way to test a given Generic parameter of a Class without any attached instance of it?

```
class BAG[G -> MOUSE]

feature -- 

    discriminate
        do
            if G.conforms_to (MAMMAL) then
                io.putstring ("you gave me a real animal")
            elseif G.conforms_to (COMPUTER_ACCESSORY) then
                io.putstring ("Seems you don't like animals such as computers")
            else
                io.pustring ("Still dont know what you are dealing with")
            end
        end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've almost nailed it. The missing part is curly braces and parentheses:

```
        if ({G}).conforms_to ({MAMMAL}) then
            io.put_string ("You gave me a real animal.")
        elseif ({G}).conforms_to ({COMPUTER_ACCESSORY}) then
            io.put_string ("Seems you don't like animals such as computers.")
        else
            io.put_string ("Still don't know what you are dealing with.")
        end
```

Explanation:

1. `{FOO}`, where `FOO` is a type name, stands for a type object. It works for any type, including formal generics, thus `{G}` and `{MAMMAL}`.
2. The syntax `{FOO}.bar` is reserved for non-object calls. But here we want an object call on the type object. Therefore, `{G}` is enclosed in parentheses: `({G}).conforms_to` (instead of `{G}.conforms_to`).

Comment: Definitly as an amazing language is Eiffel, your knowledge is as such... THX!